# Ugly nine-patches, not scaling right

Tags: android, nine-patch

A made some nine-patches for my buttons in Android but they scale in an ulgy way. The weird thing is that they are only ugly in one specific Android project.

[image]

I have no idea what cause the nine-patch to scale bad. This is the XML used in the badly scaled project, it is the same in the good scaled project.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/issueShare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Delen" />
```

Comment: I would suggest using "wrap_content" for layout height, then giving it padding as needed.  Layouts are affected by their parents as well though, so can you include the full layout files they're being used in?

Comment: Oh I had that but tested how it would work with a fixed height but that doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on a place I would never look. The problem was that in my Android Manifest I didn't specify the `android:targetSdkVersion`, only the `minSdkVersion`. After setting the `android:targetSdkVersion` the nine-patches scaled fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to the density of the phone, is the nine-path in the drawable folder only? or do you have a version of it in each of the drawable specific density folders?

Comment: nope I didn't specify an image for each desitiy but I found the problem, see my own answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: nice! im glad you found the problem :)